# jquery selector :button vs button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

What is the difference between the jquery selector ":button" and "button". The jquery documentation api says ":button" selects all button elements, but that's what normal jquery selectors do and if I select the button with a normal selector "button", it seems to return the exact same jquery object. What is the purpose of ":button" and since ":button" has less performance, then normal selectors. Is there a reason to use it over "button"?

```
<button id="i1"></button>
<button id="i2"></button>

$(":button").html("button");//works
$("button").html("button2"); works and seems to return same jquery object.
```

http://api.jquery.com/button-selector/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$('button')` to select `<button>` only

Use `$(':button')` to select `<input type="button">` and `<button>`

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation

> Selects all button elements and elements of type button.

It also further states:

> An equivalent selector to `$( ":button" )` using valid CSS is `$( "button, input[type='button']" )`

So `button` will match:

```
<button></button>
```

`:button` will match:

```
<button></button>
<input type="button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Its cleary written in the api documentation that `:button` doesn't use native querySelectorAll() method.

> Because :button is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :button cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method.